# Testing NEON SIMD registers for equality over all lanes

Tags: arm, simd, intrinsics, neon

I'm using [Neon Instrinics](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491i/Badcdfad.html) with clang.

I want to test two `uint32x4_t` SIMD values for equality over all lanes.
So not 4 test results, but one single result that tells me if A and B are equal for all lanes.

On Intel AVX, I would use something like:

```
_mm256_testz_si256( _mm256_xor_si256( A, B ), _mm256_set1_epi64x( -1 ) )
```

What would be a good way to perform an all-lane equality test for NEON SIMD?

I am assuming I will need intrinsics that operate across lanes.
Does ARM Neon have those features?

Comment: Related to [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9068959/3156750), and it all generally reduces to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15389539/3156750). Also note that if the thing that you would do based on the result can be possibly be expressed as (or transformed into) a vector conditional select, life becomes considerably easier.

Comment: Note that even your AVX version is non-optimal. Think about a bit of DeMorgan and try again.

Comment: @EOF: Since PTEST is 2 uops on Intel, and can't macro-fuse with a branch, this is at least as good and sometimes better: `0xFFFFFFFFU == _mm256_movemask_epi8( _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(A,B))`.  (`PCMPEQB/PMOVMSKB/cmp eax, imm8/je` = 3 uops to branch on it), compared to the alternative (even when implemented correctly so it doesn't need any extra constants: `__m256i diff = xor(A,B);` `_mm256_testz_si256(diff,diff)` (`PXOR / PTEST / JE` = 4 uops to branch on it.)  On AMD, PMOVMSKB and PTEST are both 2 uops, but I think you still break even because cmp/jcc can still fuse.

Comment: @PeterCordes: According to Agner Fog's tables, `pmovmskb` has 3 cycles latency on Haswell/Broadwell, and 2-3 cycles on Skylake (it's unclear under what circumstances it's 2 cycles). `ptest` is 2 cycles on Haswell/Broadwell, and 3 cycles on Skylake. I'd say pre-Skylake `ptest` is at least competitive.

Comment: @EOF: branch prediction + speculative execution means that JCC is not on the critical path.  If the flags were part of a loop-carried data dependency, this would matter, but one extra cycle to detect a branch mispredict is unlikely to matter if the throughput gain of one fewer fused-domain uop is useful.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Ah, that's a fair point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
uint16x4_t t = vqmovn_u32(veorq_u32(a, b));
vget_lane_u64(vreinterpret_u64_u16(t), 0) == 0
```

I expect the compiler to find target-specific optimizations when implementing that test.

---

I just realised something handy...

If you want to test that all lanes are less than some power of two, you can do this by replacing `vqmovn_u32()` with `vqshrn_n_u32()`; and I believe this can be extended to being within +/- a power of two (including the lower bound, excluding the upper bound) for signed types using `vqrshrn_n_s32()`.  For example, you should be able to accept both -1 and 0 in a single test using `vqrshrn_n_s32(x, 1)`.

Comment: @Notlikethat That's what the `q` in `vqmovn` is for.  If the original value is out of range then it's saturated to 0xffff.

Comment: Ah, right, that completely slipped by me. Flippin' NEON intrinsics with their flippin' `q`s everywhere, you get so used to filtering them out...

Answer (score 2):

If your just want to know if two vectors are equal or not, try following code:

```
result = vceqq_u32(a, b);
if (vminvq_u32(result ) != 0xffffffff) {
     // not equal
} else {
     // equal
}
```

See ARM's manual: [CMEQ](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0802b/CMEQ_advsimd_reg_vector.html) and [UMINV](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0802b/UMINV_advsimd_vector.html)